# How can I search for highlighted text in a RichTextBox Control

Tags: c#, winforms, search, richtextbox, highlight

In a C# forms app, how can I search for highlighted text in a RichTextBox, like that available in Microsoft Word using the ‘Find and Replace’ format option.

There does not appear to be a field in the RichTextBoxFinds Enum that has this option.  If I search for what I want to do on Google, I can find plenty of examples of how to search for text and highlight it, but nothing to find text that is highlighted.  I also cannot find anything relating to this subject on the Stack Overflow site.

I am seeking suggestions on methods I could potentially use to do this, or ways to approach the problem.

### Update

I have now created the below code in response to feedback to search for highlighted text (SelectionBackColour not white) in a RichTextBox which works but appears dreadfully slow compared to using Find to search for a string.  I can speed things up if I set the HideSelection property to true before I start the loop, but still to slow, and when it enters the loop, the RichTextBox just turns dark grey until the loop is exited and I set HideSelection false again.  What could be limiting the speed?

```
private bool FindNextH(int hightLightColour, int selectionStart, int selectionEnd)
    {
        int matchColour = hightLightColour;
        bool matchHighlight = true;
        if (matchColour == -1)   // White
        {
            matchHighlight = false;
        }
        int state = 0;
        int highlightStart = 0;
        int highlightLength = 0;
        int highlight = -1;
        bool found = false;
        richTextBox1.SelectionStart = selectionStart;
        richTextBox1.SelectionLength = 1;
        for (int i = selectionStart; i <= selectionEnd; i++)
        {
            richTextBox1.SelectionStart = i;
            int colour = richTextBox1.SelectionBackColor.ToArgb();
            switch (state)
            {
                case 0:
                    if (colour != -1)
                    {
                        if (matchHighlight)
                        {
                            if (colour == matchColour)
                            {
                                state = 1;
                                highlightStart = i;
                                highlight = colour;
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            state = 1;
                            highlightStart = i;
                            highlight = colour;
                        }
                    }
                    break;
                case 1:
                    if ((colour != highlight) || (i == selectionEnd))
                    {
                        highlightLength = i - highlightStart;
                        richTextBox1.SelectionStart = highlightStart;
                        richTextBox1.SelectionLength = highlightLength;
                        textBox2.Text = richTextBox1.SelectedText;
                        found = true;
                    }
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
            if (found)
            {
                break;
            }
        }
        return found;
    }
```

Further testing has been done to quantify timings as follows:

Rich Text File containing 30,093 words, 137,984 characters (no spaces), 167,844 characters with spaces.  ‘TestWord’ is contained in the file just over halfway through and is highlighted green.

Using Microsoft Word’s ‘Find and Replace’ (Ctrl H), with ‘Format’ set to ‘Highlight’ and the ‘Find what’ blank, it takes approximately one second for the document to scroll to the found highlighted word, starting with the cursor at the first character.  If I use ‘Find and Replace’ to search for the text, no formatting, then it takes about the same time.

If I run a test using ‘richTextBox1.Find’ to search for ‘TestWord’, it takes between 5 and 15 ms to execute, and the text in the richTextBox1 jumps to it instantaneously, so very quick.

If I run a test using my function ‘FindNextH()’, it takes approximately 3.8 seconds to find the highlighted text, if I set ‘richTextBox1.HideSelection’ to ‘true’ before calling the function, and returning it to ‘false’ afterwards.  During the 3.8 seconds, the richTextBox1 window goes dark gey and the text disappears, returning only when the highlighted word has been found.

If ‘richTextBox1.HideSelection’ is set to ‘false’ before calling ‘FindNextH(), it takes approximately  50 seconds to find the highlighted word, during which time you can the cursor scrolling through the text.

What can I do to speed this up?  Clearly Microsoft have cracked it in MS Word.  It is a pity that this feature is not a part of the ‘Find’ method.

Code that calls the two search functions below for reference:

```
        richTextBox1.HideSelection = false;
        stopWatch.Start();
        int IndexOfSearchResultFound = richTextBox1.Find(_SearchKeyword, _KeywordSelectionStart, _KeywordSelectionEnd,
                    RichTextBoxFinds.None | RichTextBoxFinds.WholeWord | RichTextBoxFinds.MatchCase);
        stopWatch.Stop();
        richTextBox1.HideSelection = false;
        TimeSpan timeDelay = stopWatch.Elapsed;



        richTextBox1.HideSelection = true;
        stopWatch.Start();
        found = FindNextH(colour, selectionStart, selectionEnd);
        stopWatch.Stop();
        richTextBox1.HideSelection = false;
        TimeSpan timeDelay = stopWatch.Elapsed;
```

Comment: Highlighted text is presumably selected text, not text in a particular color. The `RichTextBox.SelectionType` property will tell you if anything is selected, the `SelectedText` or `SelectedRtf` will tell you what is selected, the `Selection` property returns an object describing the selection, etc.

Comment: @NetMage Thank you for the prompt reply.  In answer to your question, no, I want to search for occurrences of text that have been highlighted using ‘richTextBox1.SelectionBackColor = dlg.Color’.  So, I am looking for blocks of highlighting, like you can do using the Word ‘Find and Replace’ format option (highlight).  At present, I want to search for any highlight, but maybe in the future, I might want to specify the highlight colour I wish to search for.  Hope this helps clarify my question.

Comment: if you are changing the `SelectionBackColor` than you are affecting the selection, not general blocks of text. Even in Word, you can't find the selection that way so you should just use the selection properties I listed.

Comment: In Word, if I highlight several words and sections of text in yellow, then I can search for anything that is highlighted and it will jump to the highlighted words and text selections.  I didn’t release Word could do this until someone told me today – great feature.  I want to be able to do the same.

Comment: Write a function to test for highlighting and do a normal find. Then test each character/index for the length of the needle!

Comment: @TaW OK, that makes sense.  So, I test a character at a time using ‘SelectionBackColor’ to check for highlighting, and then when I find a group of consecutive highlighted characters, I select them as the first find.  This will also give me the option to search for a specific highlight colour which I will include.  I will have a go at writing a function for this and post here once I have got it working.  Thanks for the replies this evening, I didn’t expect to get a response so quickly.

Comment: @TaW Created some code that works, but runs too slow (question updated with code included).  Any thoughts on how to speed this up?

Comment: Maybe you should add a few numbers, like length of text, needle and ca. timings. You call this function to further test findings from a normal find, right?

Comment: @TaW Updated the question to include additional info as suggested.  The 'RichTextBox' 'Find' method is clearly very quick.  Not sure if the code for that method is readily available, but could shed some light on how to write a much faster 'find highlight' function.  Any thoughts?